# Hibernate filter not getting applied within Async process

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, aspect, hibernate-session, hibernate-filters

I have a hibernate filter defined on my entities which I am injecting using aspect for all repositories which implements my TenantableRepository.

The issue is that the filter is not getting injected in the repository calls executed within CompletetableFuture method. But filter is getting injected properly outside it.
I understand that the threads are different but aspect is being called both the times though.

I want the filter to get enabled from all flows. API or async processes.

Here is the Aspect I have defined to work on all TenantableRepositories' methods starting with find.

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TenantFilterAspect {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Before("execution(* com.demo.repository.TenantableRepository+.find*(..))")
    public void beforeFindOfTenantableRepository() {
        log.info("Called aspect");
        entityManager
                .unwrap(Session.class)
                .enableFilter(Tenantable.TENANT_FILTER_NAME)
                .setParameter(Tenantable.TENANT_COLUMN, TenantContext.getTenantId());
    }
}
```

I have a controller to test the flow. Here I am making 2 repository calls. One in main thread and one under async `CompletetableFuture` method.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/api/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/aysnc", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<APIResponse> testAsync(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws InterruptedException {
        Optional<MyEntity> entity = myEntityRepository.findByFirstName("Firstname");
        if(!entity.isEmpty()){
            log.info("1. Main: found entity:{}",entity.get());
        }
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::callAsyncMethod);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body("Ok");
    }

    public void callAsyncMethod() {
        Optional<MyEntity> entity = myEntityRepository.findByFirstName("Firstname");
        if(!entity.isEmpty()){
            log.info("2. Async: found entity:{}",entity.get());
        }
    }

}
```

The issue is that the filter is not getting injected in the repo call under async `CompletetableFuture` method `callAsyncMethod()`. But filter is getting injected properly in first repo call before async method.
I understand that the threads are different but aspect is being called both the times. I get the log printed but the filter is still not enabled.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Let me guess your `TenantContext.getTenantId` is based on a `ThreadLocal`. What do you think happens to the value bound to thread 1 when you execute in thread 2.

Comment: @M.Deinum TenantContext is InheritableThreadLocal. And I see tenant context available with thread 2 also.

Comment: I doubt it still is there as, if you are unlucky, the thread already cleaned up the resources before the other one executes.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am able to log tenant ID in the thread 2 when aspect gets called.

Comment: The problem is, I suspect, the fact that you have multiple entitymanagers. As there is no transactional bound entitymanger, you get 2 different ones. 1 for the aspect and one for the repository. This isn't the case in the normal execution as by default open-entitymanager in view is applied and you have 1 entitymanager. If you would call this in an `@Transactional` service method it would work as it would use a shared entitymanager. I suspect the same would happen if you set `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` in your `application.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot by default enables the Open Entitymanager In View pattern. Which means for the whole duration of the HTTP Request there is 1 single `EntityManager` available. This `EntityManager` is bound to the request handling thread using a `ThreadLocal`.

Now when executing the first `findByFirstName` it will operate on this shared `EntityManager`.

Your second call, which is done on a different thread doesn't see this shared `EntityManager`. As there is also no transactional context, which would create another thread bound `EntityManager`, the Aspect will get a fresh `EntityManager`. However the `EntityManager` used by the Aspect is discarded right after that because, as mentioned, no transactional context. Next it reaches the actual repository method, which doesn't see an active `EntityManager` either and gets a fresh one as well (without any filters applied because those were applied to another `EntityManager` instance).

When you set the `spring.jpa.open-in-view` property to `false` I the same will happen with the first call to `findByFirstName` as that disables the shared `EntityManager`.

The problem with this code is that this should be called from inside an `@Transactional` service method. The `@Transactional` will lead to the creation of a shared (thread-bound) `EntityManager` for the duration of the transaction.

```java
@Service
public MyEntityService {

  private final MyEntityRepository repo;

  public MyEntityService(MyEntityRepository repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
  }
  

  @Transactional
  public Optional<MyEntity> findByFirstname(String firstname) {
    return repo.findByFirstName(firstname);
  }
}
```

Now if you would inject this service into your controller (as you should have done anyway), it will work due to the shared `EntityManager` for each call due to the `@Transactional`.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. Now I understand that EntityManagers are different between both the threads. But I am still unclear on why Aspect is being called twice? Is it called twice with the same first EntityManager? Does that mean Aspect cannot be called outside the REST API scope ?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be called twice? YOu are executing the method twice. But in total there are 3 `EntityManager` instancs in play. The first invocation of `findByFirstName` is part of the request procssing thread which uses 1 `EntityManager` due to open-entitymanager-in-view. The second call to `findByFirstName` uses 2 `EntityManager` s one for the aspect (which is discarded afterwards) and one for the actual `findByFirstName` method (which doesn't have the filter applied obviously because it is a fresh one).

Comment: Why 2nd EntityManager gets discarded? And even if new EntityManagers are being created, why filters don't get applied to those?

Comment: Why should the get applied for each entitymanager?. The filter is applied **before the execution of the `findByFirstName` method on the repository**. That is exactly what it is doing, as there is no point to keep the entitymanager open (no transactional context) it gets discarded right after executing the aspect. As soon as the actual method on the repository is invoked that retrieves a new one (because there wasn't one anyway). Which is why you should always use this in a transactional context (as explained in the answer!).

Comment: Ok so are you saying that for the second thread, there is no attached default Transaction and so even if we do multiple  findByFirstName calls within that same child thread then all will use its own new EntityManagers? And aspect will be called each time but that EntityManagers gets closed and is not reused by repo call. 
If I use @Transactional annotation issue will get resolved. But is there something which I can configure at framework level or commonly so not every team member has to remember to put @Transactional?

Comment: No as data access should always be done in a transaction. Next to that you shouldn't be sharing entitymanagers / hibernate sesssions between threads as that will lead to all sorts of weird issues.

Comment: Also for the first thread there is also no default transaction there is only open-entitymanager in view which has nothing to do with transactions. The important part is you need to make sure that there is always a threadbound entitymanager, which can be achieved using transactions (which is basically how to properly use things like this).

Comment: This is really helpful. Summarising.
-Sessions/EntityManagers are not thread safe so new sessions are created per thread by spring.
-Even within a single thread, if piece of code is not annotated with Transactional then each data access call will use new sessions and won't share it.
-Transactional annotation will make sure that particular piece of code uses same Session. Again @Transactional annotation also works in a single thread context and does not propogate to new threads spawn from there.

Comment: Thanks @M. Deinum for your help. I have summarised our discussion. Feel free to add if I have missed anything or wrongly quoted.